# Aggregate the total sum of aggregation field

Tags: php, elasticsearch, aggregate, elasticsearch-2.0, nosql-aggregation

**Hi all,
I'm trying with no luck so far, to aggregate the total impressions sum of impressions field, but I keep getting an error.
I got the following query:**

```
 GET smarttag-2016.06.28.*/_search?search_type=count
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [{
        "range": {
          "@timestamp": {
            "gte": "2016-06-28T10:00:00",
            "lt": "2016-06-28T11:00:00"
          }
        }
      }],
      "must_not": [
        {
          "term": {
            "tagType": {
              "value": "app"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "TagId": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "TagId",
        "size": 0
      },
      "aggs": {
        "name": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "url",
            "size": 0
          },
          "aggs": {
            "tagType": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "type"
              },
              "aggs": {
                "impressions": {
                  "sum": {
                    "field": "imp"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          } 
        }
      }
    },
    "sum_imp": {
      "sum_bucket": {
          "buckets_path": "TagId>name>tagType>impressions"
          }
      }
  }
}
```

The error:

```
  {
       "error": {
          "root_cause": [],
          "type": "reduce_search_phase_exception",
          "reason": "[reduce] ",
          "phase": "query",
          "grouped": true,
          "failed_shards": [],
          "caused_by": {
             "type": "aggregation_execution_exception",
             "reason": "buckets_path must reference either a number value or a single value numeric metric aggregation, got: java.lang.Object[]"
          }
       },
       "status": 503
    }
```

I don't understand what am I doing wrong.

Comment: I think the "size:0" under the name agg might be the issue maybe?

Comment: I don't think. I removed it and I still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

i think that the problem is related with the "TagId>name>tagType>impressions"
part. i.e. pipeline bucket aggregation going down more than 2 levels.
I hope you have solved the problem. I am facing this also.